# Variable Colors in Google Bar Charts

Tags: charts, colors, google-visualization

I have a survey web app that serves a number different kinds of questions to Google Chart. In fact there are 26 of them. I need to change the colors of the bars depending on the question case. I CAN accomplish this, by copying the *var options* inside of each *if (questioncase = 'X')* **26 times** - but I'm hoping for a short cut. Any thoughts would, as always be, much appreciated.

```
var options = {
 //width:w,
 width:500,
 height:h,
 isStacked:true,
 chartArea:{height:chartHeight,left:l,width:cw},
 backgroundColor:'transparent',
 bar:{groupWidth:'80%'},
 tooltip: {isHtml:true},
 legend:{position:pos,maxLines:50},
 hAxis: {title: 'Percentage',minValue:0,maxValue:100},
 hAxis: { textPosition: 'none',ticks: [0]},
 colors: ['#eeeeee', '#eeeeee', '#e4d00a', '#b30000', '#990000']
 }

if (questioncase == 'A') {

    var options = {
        colors: ['#134e13', '#008900', '#e4d00a', '#b30000', '#990000']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse the same `options` object, just change the `colors` property.

```
if (questioncase == 'A') {
  options.colors = ['#134e13', '#008900', '#e4d00a', '#b30000', '#990000'];
}
```

Comment: or maybe I misunderstood the question...?

Comment: No - that's it! Holy smokes...I'm a newbie and all, but I swear I scoured the earth for this answer - I must have brushed against it, but just tanked the syntax. It looks so simple after someone tells you what to do...Thank you WhiteHat!

Comment: cheers! always glad to help, good luck with your project. if you get stuck, get my attention...